# Overloading for pass-by-value and pass-by-rvalue-reference

Tags: c++11, parameter-passing, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have two overloads of a subroutine that takes an argument of a type that occupies several Megabytes of dynamic memory and has a move constructor and assignment operator:

```
// Version intended for use when we the caller has 
// deliberately passed an rvalue reference using std::move
void MyClass::setParameter(MyMoveableType &&newParameter)
{
    m_theLocalParameter = std::move(newParameter);
}

// Version intended for use when the caller has passed
// some other type of value which shouldn't be moved
void MyClass::setParameter(MyMoveableType newParameter) 
{
    m_theLocalParameter = std::move(newParameter);
}
```

The intention is clearly that the first overload moves the contents of newParameter from wherever up the chain of subroutine-calls the newParameter object originated, whilst the second overload creates a brand new copy of newParameter (or invokes copy elision to avoid doing so where appropriate, such as where the argument is actually the return value from a function) and then moves the copy into the local data member, thus avoiding a further copy.

However, if I try actually to move an object into my class using the first overload:

```
{
    MyClass        theDestination;
    MyMoveableType theObject
    ...
    // ...Various actions which populate theObject...
    ...

    TheDestination.setParameter(std::move(theObject));
    ...
}
```

...then on every compiler I've tried I get an error along the lines of:

```
call to member function 'setParameter' is ambiguous
```

Now I can see that passing an rvalue reference to the second overload would in fact be perfectly legal, and is what I'd expect the compiler to do, without giving a warning, if I hadn't provided the first overload. Even so, I'd expect it to be perfectly clear to the compiler what the intent of this code is, and therefore I'd expect that it would select the second overload as being the best match.

I can eliminate the error by redefining the second constructor to take a const reference and do away with the std::move (though it wouldn't be an error to 
leave it in; the compiler would just ignore it). This would work all right, but I'd lose the opportunity to take advantage of copy elision. This could be 
significant in performance terms for this particular application; the objects under discussion are high-resolution video frames streaming through at 30 
frames per second.

Is there anything I can do under this circumstance to disambiguate the overloads and so have both a pass-by-value and pass-by-rvalue-reference version of my routine?

Comment: Have you figured out why the function call is ambiguous? I'm having a similar problem, and can't rationalise why we have ambiguity here. I would have thought that the second function is called whenever the parameter is an rvalue, else the first would be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The intention is clearly that the first overload moves the contents of newParameter from wherever up the chain of subroutine-calls the newParameter object originated, whilst the second overload creates a brand new copy

Which is not really how you do it. You have two sane options:

#### Approach A

You write *just the value overload* and then move from it anyway - that means you'll always pay a constructor price, either move or copy.

#### Approach B

You write overloads for `(const T&)` and `(T&&)`. That way you copy in the first one and skip the move CTOR in the second one using perfect forwarding.

---

I recommend approach A as a default, and B only when the c-tor call actually matters that much.

Comment: Thank you. I find it disappointing that the language implements such useful features as copy elision and move semantics, and then prevents them from being used together! A bit like giving with one hand and taking away with the other.

Comment: Can you give more details about why you recommend approach `A` over B? Its only because with approach `A` you need to write just the value overload?

Comment: @Vasilly.Prokopyev it's shorter and easier to read for a newcomer.

Comment: Would you be able to explain why the function call is ambiguous? :)

Comment: @BaranKarakus Assuming explicit `move` scenario, an rvalue generated that way can bind to either `T&&` or `T`. The OP assumed that the `T&&` will take precedence, while the "Approach B" above is the correct way to remove that ambiguity

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I understand that the rvalue can bind to either `T&&` or `T`, but the crux of the issue seems to be that it will not prefer to bind to one over the other, right? By contrast, if one defines a function taking a `const T&` and then a `T&&` overload, rvalues can bind to either of them, but will prefer the latter?

Comment: @BaranKarakus Yes, that's exactly what happens.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz thanks for clarifying :).